# Finding order of segments of a road based on two columns (Start and End)

Tags: sql, pandas

[image: Sample Table]

I have a table of the above logic, where I have a road that made up of segments and each segment have a start and stop node. How can I sort the table such that for each road, the segments are sorted in their relative order (which is not in numerical order but dependent on the start and end node)? Also after that I want to add two columns, 'Start' and 'End', to provide the start and end node of the road. The output of the above table should be

[image: Expected Output]

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [['Road_id','Segment_id','Start_node','End_node'], [1,8285,4740,4741], [1,8509,4741,5144], [1,8437, 5016,5017], [1,8447, 5031, 5016], [1, 8520, 5144,5168], [1,9104,5168,4785],[1,8550,5017,4740]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])
```

Comment: how to know which is the first Start_node ?  ie 5031 is the first Start_node ?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake again, I think I will have to repost the question with edits

Comment: Think you revert this question with the data = [['Road_id','Segment_id','Start_node','End_node'], [1,8285,4740,4741], [1,8509,4741,5144], [1,8437, 5016,5017], [1,8447, 5031, 5016], [1, 8520, 5144,5168], [1,9104,5168,4785]] data.  If not, in the future, other people reading will get confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [['Road_id','Segment_id','Start_node','End_node'], [1,8285,4740,4741], [1,8509,4741,5144], [1,8437, 5016,5017], [1,8447, 5031, 5016], [1, 8520, 5144,5168], [1,9104,5168,4785]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0]) 
df = df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))
df
```

[image]

```
df.sort_values(['Start_node','End_node'])
```

[image]

Comment: @WeeHowChan updated with your new data.  Your data is already sorted. I permutate the rows and then run the sort.  Perhaps you could try it on your data to have a look, then feedback exactly what you're seeing ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and sorry for missing a row in my sample data. The issue that I encountered sadly isn't able to be resolve with your suggested code.

Comment: @WeeHowChan You changed the question completely.  It should be a new question.  The original question was already answered.

Comment: Sorry about that